# Why is my fscanf not working?

Tags: c++

For some reason I have no idea why, my fscanf code does not work. My friend with the same assignment and the same code works for him.

```
ISBNPrefix::ISBNPrefix(const char * filename) {
    FILE * prefixFile = NULL;

    if (filename != NULL)
    prefixFile = fopen(filename, "r");
}

bool ISBNPrefix::isRegistered (int area) const {
    int areaDigit = 0;
    bool check = false;

    //rewind(prefixFile);

    while(fscanf(prefixFile, "%d %*[^ ] %*[^\n]", &areaDigit) != EOF) {
        if (areaDigit == area) {
            check = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return check;
}
```

It does not fscanf properly, it should return true on some tests but it returns false; I don't think it's scanning properly. Can anyone see what's wrong?

The first four lines of my text file are:

```
0 00 19
0 200 699
0 7000 8499
0 85000 89999
```

Comment: It usually helps to provide a minimal example: a piece of code (and sample input) that others can run to reproduce your error. Dumping some out of context code sometimes makes it harder to help.

Comment: The entire program is way too long for me to copy and paste all of it. i tried to include what was relevant. @chrisaycock there are 3 parts of the file line, and in that function I only check for the first part

Comment: But I added the %*[^ ] the "*" which says not to save that part. My friend has the same code and it works for him. @chrisaycock

Comment: @user2140629 the idea isn't to dump large amounts of code, its to provide a new program that is small and has the same error so that people don't have to look at things like `ISBNPrefix::isRegistered` which are not relevant to your problem and can maybe even run your code and get the same error (or not! :))

Comment: @chrisaycock: the `*` in the scanf specifer says "match this thing, but then throw it away rather than saving it", so is perfectly reasonable

Comment: You need to define 'does not fscanf properly' -- what exactly is going wrong?  What is the input you're trying to read and what unexpected thing is happening that you are suprised about?

Comment: @ChrisDodd The program is really complicated and it comes with a test main to test the cpp code, I wouldn't know where to begin with explaining. I was just asking if the while(fscanf()) code itself contains any errors which would cause an error

Comment: @user2140629: You need to define what it is you think is an error.  The line is reasonable for some things but not for others.  What exactly is happening that makes you think it's wrong?  Does it crash?  Go into an infinite loop?  Return true when you think it should return false?

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
while(fscanf(prefixFile, "%d %*[^ ] %*[^\n]", &areaDigit) != EOF) {
```

will

- read a number into areaDigit, then
- skip whitespace in the input, then
- read one or more non-space characters, then
- skip whitespace again, then
- read and discard all characters up to the next newline.

Should it get to the end of the file BEFORE reading the number for `areaDigit`, the loop will end.  So for example with an input like:

```
123 456 789
555 xxx yyy
```

it will loop twice with `areaDigit` as 123 and 555

With an input like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
a b c d e f g h i
```

it will read `1` and then go into an infinite loop failing to read the second line (with `areaDigit == 1` the whole time.)

With an input like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

it will loop 3 times with `areaDigit` as 1, 4, and 7

Comment: So would a fix be to scan all 3 parts without the "*"? Ill edit my question with an example of the first 4 lines of the text file

Comment: @user2140629: A fix for what?  You still haven't said what is wrong, or what you expect, or what you are trying to acheive.